# Как добавить при помощи js проверку правильного ответа?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как добавить при помощи js проверку правильного ответа?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: правильные ответы известны заранее? Приведите код и/или дополните вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Ну, например так:

```js
var x = 4; //правильный ответ
var resultContainer = document.getElementById('result');

function check(n) {
  if (n == x) {
    resultContainer.innerHTML = '<span class="g">Правильно!</span>';
  } else {
    resultContainer.innerHTML = '<span class="r">Неправильно! Верный ответ - ' + x + '</span>';
  }
}
```

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
}

.btn {
  width: unset;
  margin-right: 3%;
  padding: 3% 5%;
  float: left;
  color: gray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#result { 
  width: 100vw; 
  margin-top: 15%;
}
#result span { font-size: 22px; }
#result span.g { color: green; }
#result span.r { color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h2>2+2=?</h2>
  <div>
    <div class="btn" onClick="check('3')">3</div>
    <div class="btn" onClick="check('5')">5</div>
    <div class="btn" onClick="check('4')">4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

P.S.: Сообщество не приветствует вопросы из разряда "сделайте всё за меня", в следующий раз попробуй сам разобраться, и если не будет получаться, уже можно скинуть сюда свой код и попросить о помощи.